How can I automate video recording duration (and frequency) in Kotlin? [UPDATE Nov 22 -2024] Now permissions
I have been working on an app used for video recording of sparring rounds (in boxing). On a more fundamental basis, it should be a loop that records automatically for as long (in minutes) and as many times (rounds) as the user inputs. Right now this is a proof-of-concept;
So far, I have been able to access the user's camera, but I cannot figure out how to set the auto-recording or make the loop work. I am wondering if I am accessing the camera properly or if I need to make changes, or if this can even be done in Kotlin.
There are three variables that the user inputs:

numberOfRounds, integer
lenghtOfRounds, integer
breakRounds, integer

Here is my code:
private fun startRecordingLoop() {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    var currentRound = 1

    fun recordRound() {
        if (currentRound <= numberOfRounds) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startRecording()

            handler.postDelayed({
                stopRecording()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Break round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                currentRound++

                handler.postDelayed({ recordRound() }, breakRounds * 60 * 1000L)
            }, lengthOfRound * 60 * 1000L)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "All rounds completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    recordRound()
}

private fun startRecording() {
    try {
        if (!::mediaRecorder.isInitialized) {
            mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        }

These are the projects imports:
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.File

This is the code for the AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

[UPDATE 11/22/2024]
I have updated how to access the camera (thanks Tyler!) and now there are no more deprecation problems. I made modifications to the recording loop to access the camera and I have reached the point where the camera is launching, the toasts regarding the completion of the rounds -indicates that the round has started, the round has ended, and that all the rounds have been recorded-, but it is not generating any video file. What I get out of this is: the recording loop works but is flawed. It is accessing the camera but it is not saving the file. This is the loop as of right now:
   private fun startRecordingLoop() {
        var currentRound = 1

        fun recordRound() {
            if (currentRound <= numberOfRounds) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                startRecording()

                textureView.postDelayed({
                    stopRecording()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Break round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    currentRound++

                    textureView.postDelayed({ recordRound() }, breakRounds * 60 * 1000L)
                }, lengthOfRound * 60 * 1000L)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "All rounds completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                showInputs()
            }
        }

        hideInputs()
        recordRound()
    }

Now the app is displayed in landscape mode, and once the user hits the start recording button, the UI hides and it "returns" once all the rounds have been filmed. At least, that's what should do in theory.
Since I believe the problem of the camera not filming is the permissions request, I have been focusing on that path, but now the code gets stuck in a loop of request permissions, but does not ask for all of them. I will report once I make improvements on that end. Below you will see the whole code of the app, kindly let me know if you see something wrong that I may have overlooked.
Thank you all again for your help and kindness!!
Code, last update [11/22/2024]
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture
import android.hardware.camera2.*
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Surface
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.File
import android.content.Intent



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    // Variables for user inputs
    private var numberOfRounds: Int = 0
    private var lengthOfRound: Int = 0
    private var breakRounds: Int = 0

    // Camera and MediaRecorder variables
    private lateinit var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
    private lateinit var textureView: TextureView
    private lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice
    private lateinit var cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession
    private var isRecording = false
    private var permissionAttempts = 0 // Track permission request attempts

    // Permissions required for the app
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize TextureView for the camera preview
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView)
        textureView.surfaceTextureListener = this // Register the TextureView listener

        // Check and request permissions at app launch
        if (!allPermissionsGranted()) {
            requestPermissions()
        } else {
            initializeApp() // Only initialize if all permissions are already granted
        }

        // UI elements for user input
        val roundsInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.roundsInput)
        val lengthInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.lengthInput)
        val breakInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.breakInput)
        val startButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.startButton)

        // Start the recording loop when the button is clicked
        startButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                // Parse input values
                numberOfRounds = roundsInput.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
                lengthOfRound = lengthInput.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
                breakRounds = breakInput.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0

                if (numberOfRounds > 0 && lengthOfRound > 0 && breakRounds > 0) {
                    startRecordingLoop() // Begin the recording loop
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid input values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required to start recording.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize app functionality after permissions are granted
    private fun initializeApp() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "App is initializing...")
        Toast.makeText(this, "App initialized successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    // Check if all required permissions are granted
    private fun allPermissionsGranted(): Boolean {
        val missingPermissions = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.filter { permission ->
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Missing permissions: $missingPermissions")
        return missingPermissions.isEmpty()
    }

    // Request all necessary permissions
    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, 102)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == 102) {
            val deniedPermissions = permissions.filterIndexed { index, _ ->
                grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            }

            if (deniedPermissions.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "All permissions granted!")
                initializeApp() // Call initializeApp only when permissions are granted
            } else {
                permissionAttempts++
                if (permissionAttempts < 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Permissions denied: $deniedPermissions. Grant them to continue.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    requestPermissions()
                } else {
                    showPermissionExplanation(deniedPermissions)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Show a dialog explaining why permissions are needed
    private fun showPermissionExplanation(deniedPermissions: List<String>) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Permissions Required")
            .setMessage("The app requires the following permissions to function: $deniedPermissions. Please grant them in Settings.")
            .setPositiveButton("Go to Settings") { _, _ ->
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Exit") { _, _ ->
                finish()
            }
            .show()
    }

    // Loop to handle recording rounds
    private fun startRecordingLoop() {
        var currentRound = 1

        fun recordRound() {
            if (currentRound <= numberOfRounds) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                startRecording()

                textureView.postDelayed({
                    stopRecording()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Break round $currentRound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    currentRound++

                    textureView.postDelayed({ recordRound() }, breakRounds * 60 * 1000L)
                }, lengthOfRound * 60 * 1000L)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "All rounds completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                showInputs()
            }
        }

        hideInputs()
        recordRound()
    }

    // Start video recording
    private fun startRecording() {
        try {
            hideInputs()
            if (!::mediaRecorder.isInitialized) {
                mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
            }

            val outputFile = getOutputFile()
            val cameraManager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
            val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList.firstOrNull {
                cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(it).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK
            } ?: throw IllegalStateException("No back-facing camera found")

            mediaRecorder.apply {
                setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER)
                setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
                setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
                setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
                setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000)
                setVideoFrameRate(30)
                setVideoSize(1920, 1080)
                prepare()
                start()
            }
            isRecording = true
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error starting recording: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    // Stop video recording
    private fun stopRecording() {
        try {
            if (isRecording) {
                mediaRecorder.stop()
                mediaRecorder.reset()
                isRecording = false
                showInputs()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error stopping recording: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    // Helper functions
    private fun hideInputs() {
        findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.inputsLayout).visibility = View.GONE
    }

    private fun showInputs() {
        findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.inputsLayout).visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun getOutputFile(): File {
        val directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        if (directory != null && !directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs()
        }
        return File(directory, "video_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4")
    }

    // TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener methods
    override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
        try {
            val cameraManager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
            val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList.firstOrNull {
                cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(it).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK
            } ?: throw IllegalStateException("No back-facing camera found")

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Handle missing permissions
                return
            }

            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    cameraDevice = camera

                    val previewSurface = Surface(surface)
                    val captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface)

                    camera.createCaptureSession(listOf(previewSurface), object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                            cameraCaptureSession = session
                            session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                        }

                        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to configure camera session")
                        }
                    }, null)
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Camera disconnected")
                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error opening camera: $error")
                }
            }, null)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error initializing camera preview: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
        // Handle size changes if necessary
    }

    override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
        // Close the camera when the surface is destroyed
        cameraDevice.close()
        return true
    }

    override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {
        // Handle texture updates if necessary
    }
}



Does this help with regard to auto-recording? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953138/android-how-to-start-recording-video-automatically-when-calling-the-camera-int

Hi Tyler! thank you so much! That content and my code are in the same direction, but we run into the same issue. The problem I keep encountering, if I can even call it a problem is that MediaRecorder seems to be a deprecated method, and my fear is that because of that it would prompt more problems. I am finishing my coffee as we speak, I am going to revisit the code and will report in a few! Thank you again for your help

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598179/deprecated-mediarecorder-new-mediarecorder only a specific implementation of MediaRecorder is deprecated, AFAIK. Here's the current full documentation on recording w/ the camera https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera-deprecated/camera-api#capture-video and it talks about using the MediaRecorder class still; look specifically at step 4a in that documentation link.

Thank you so much for your help Tyler! it was key to solving the problem. Now I am running into permissions handling problems. I will report once I fix them!
